# Number of times a number has changed in excel column

Tags: python, excel, list

I just started learning Python and need help analyzing data in an excel spreadsheet. The excel sheet has i.e. 111122221112211 in one column and I'm trying to figure out how many changes from 1 to 2 or 2 to 1 occur here. In this case, 4 times.

I've been told to use set.difference but I don't understand how. So I tried my own way and get the error 'list index out of range' at the elif part. Here is my script (I'm still working on the basics so this may seem very amateur):

```
a = xlws.Columns(5).value
a = [list(x)[0] for x in a[1:400]]

beam = 0

for x in range(len(a)):
    if a[x] ==1 and a[x+1]==2:
        beam += 1
    elif  a[x]==2 and a[x+1]==1:
        beam += 1
    else: 
        beam = beam
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `for x in range(len(a)):` should be

```
for x in range(len(a)-1):
```

because you are getting a list element with index `x+1` inside the loop and therefore you are reading one element too much.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way of computing it is by using [`izip`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip):

```
>>> from itertools import izip
>>> s = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1]
>>> answer = len(filter(lambda x: x[0] != x[1], izip(s, s[1:])))
>>> answer
4
```

The approach above is: use `s` and all elements except the first one (`s[1:]`) and create pair-wise tuples using `izip`. This creates a list such as `[(1, 1), (1, 1), ..., (1, 2)]`. We then only take the elements that have two different values (such as `(1, 2)`) using [`filter()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter).

The number of elements that have a different value is the answer to your question and we compute that by calculating the length of the list (with `len()`).

Comment: In Python3 the `filter` has to be in a call to `list` because `filter`returns an object that can not be the argument of `len`